# android:change tab style and height in android?

Tags: android

I am using a tab ,In which tab buttons add melodramatically,My requirement is to reduce the tab button height and give custom style for tab button.I am using android 1.5.My Code gives below

```
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST1_TAB_TAG).setIndicator(LIST1_TAB_TAG).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listView1;
        }

    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST2_TAB_TAG).setIndicator(LIST2_TAB_TAG).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listView2;
        }
    }));
```

please Help 

Regards Augustine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for custom tabs, this might help.

[Creating tabs programatically](http://android.attemptone.com/layouts/custom-tabs/)

[Creating tabs through xml](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

Comment: Please [provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Summarize the contents in your answer; include the links for reference. Your answer should make sense even if the links were not included.

Comment: I will try next time to be perfect.

Comment: Since there is no context for the links and to save time for those arriving in future. There is much more detail in link 2.